# What is the cheapest form of solid state usb storage that can sustain 100MB/s continuously (minimum capacity 16gb)

Tags: usb, data-storage

Anything faster cannot output data faster than gigabit ethernet, so not needed.

If you don't have anything that can do 100MB/s then what is the next best thing ?
A 16gb usb stick that can do 80MB/s is still plenty good for home assistant or nextcloud.

In this case reading is more important than write

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, a sandisk extreme pro is really fast, but if you can't afford that, the intenso Speed Line 256GB also is fast enough, and more than half the price/GB

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a cheap SATA SSD like the Samsung 860 Evo and a SATA to USB cable. This is faster and higher capacity than most USB sticks like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

SanDisk Ultra Fit **USB 3.1**; Read speeds up to 130MB/s

amazon $8 for 32gb
amazon $15 for 128gb

Other thing that comes to mind is sandisk extreme pro class 10 SDXC 16gb card, advertised around 90 MB/sec read.  Not sure about being usb 2.0 or usb 3.0 though.  Similar pricing.

double check with manufacturer and other credible sources on the advertised speeds.

[https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-128GB-Extreme-UHS-I-SDSDXXY-128G-GN4IN/dp/B07H9DVLBB/ref=psdc_1197396_t2_B07H48412Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H9DVLBB)

^^ $30 sandisk 128gb SDSDXXY-128G-GN4IN
*transfer speeds up to 170MB/s [requires a compatible device capable of reaching such speeds, such as the SanDisk SD UHS I card reader (sold separately)]*

Comment: That sandisk extreme pro card also requires an sd card reader

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link for that 8$ ultra fit usb 3.1 ? That would be perfect with a 40$ raspberry pi. A full size SD card is not really usable in a RPi, USB is really best for a boot drive as it works for everything.

Comment: I did find a "SanDisk Ultra Flair USB 3.0 16GB" that claims "up to 130MB/s" for 8.99$, but that price in on special  and the ultra fit 3.1 sounds like a better option